# SQL Task (SSIS) - An error occurred while extracting the result into a variable of type (DBTYPE_DATE)?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, bids

I have to work in an existing SSIS solution. One of the initial steps is simply truncate an existing Oracle table.

The existing problematic SQL Task is as per below (replaced the schema and table)

```
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="Expression">"truncate table schema.table"</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="EvaluateAsExpression">-1</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="Namespace">User</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="ReadOnly">0</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="RaiseChangedEvent">0</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="IncludeInDebugDump">2345</DTS:Property><DTS:VariableValue DTS:DataType="8">truncate table ledger.fusion_fx_rates_processstaging</DTS:VariableValue>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="ObjectName">SQL_VariableSQL_ClearDownFusionFXRatesProcessstaging</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="DTSID">{71911B6D-A0F8-49E4-9F7C-769BAEB5E8F9}</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="Description"></DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="CreationName"></DTS:Property></DTS:Variable>
```

The first strange to me is that when I open the task in the Control Flow, and press the "build query" button, I get the "Unable to parse query text" error. For some reason the truncate word in the statement has "", so if I remove them, and pressing the "run" button it prompts for the password of the database and it succeeds (which suggests there's no issue with the OleDB connection). However when I click ok to close the menu, I get again the "unable to parse text" error, and if I go back to the menu I was before, I have again the "" around the truncate (only on that word, not on the whole statement).

In the end, when I run the solution, I have this error in the Output:

> "An error occurred while extracting the result into a variable of type
>   (DBTYPE_DATE)". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query,
>   "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly,
>   or connection not established correctly.

In the SQL Task Edit there's no result set defined, and obviously I'm not trying to obtain any type of result with a truncate statement, so I wonder what might be the problem? I'm using BIDS 2008.

I've tried change the property of the SQLSourceType from Variable to DirectInput, and then put the SQL Statement directly, but it gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was an input parameter configured in the SQL Task Editor, which I never confirmed in first place since it was a truncate statement.

I honestly don't know how these things end up this way on Subversion and how they actually run in production...!